# How to get model name based on her slug?

Tags: php, database, laravel

I want to get the model title based on that slug.

**Here is how I get the model from database :**

```
{{ $news->model }}
```

**This returns me**

```
rebecca-david
```

and what I wanted to do is to get the value of title based on slug from `models` :

```
Rebecca David
```

**Here is my controller:**

```
  public function newsSingle($news_category, $model, $id, $slug)

    {

        // return $slug;

        $data = $this->data;

  $data['news'] = News::with('category_name','news_image','models','creative')
                ->where('slug','=',$slug)
                ->orWhere('id','=',$id)
                ->orWhere('model','=',$model)
                ->orWhere('news_category','=',$news_category)
                ->first();
}
```

I need to get model-title from table `models`, column `title` based on that `slug` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reverse the slug doing this maybe:

```
{{ ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $news->model)) }}
```